# ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in SubjectsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: created_at(2i), created_at(3i), created_at(1i), created_at(4i), created_at(5i)
```

my code is below:

```
def new
  @subject = Subject.new(:name => 'default')
  @subject_count = Subject.count + 1
end

def create
  # Instantiate a new object using form parameters
  @subject = Subject.new(params[:subject])
  # Save the object
  if @subject.save
  # If save succeeds, redirect to the list action
    flash[:notice] = "Subject created."
    redirect_to(:action => 'list')
  else
  # If save fails, redisplay the form so user can fix problems
    @subject_count = Subject.count + 1
    render('new')
```

what is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this,
In your subject model add all attributes you used in your form such as,

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :created_at
  ...
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Either set config.active_record.whitelist_attributes in application to false in application.rb (not recommended) or whitelist attributes in your model using attr_accessible as such
    attr_accessible :name, :etc...

Comment: I have whitelist attributes to false in a legacy app that needs updating to rails 3.2, but I'm still getting this error

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to whitelist the attributes sent via the controller in the `Subject` model as explained by Alex. You Subject model should look like:

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :created_at
end
```

Why? Rails requires this recently (after a [security problem on Github](http://arstechnica.com/business/2012/03/hacker-commandeers-github-to-prove-vuln-in-ruby/)) to make sure a malicious user doesn't send unwanted attributes from the frontend. Suppose you have an :admin boolean field on a User class. Without the `attr_accessible` someone could add a new field in the form, something like `<input type="checkbox" name="user[admin]" value="true" checked>`, which would give him admin powers to your application.

Sidenote... you don't need to set the :created_at date from the HTML form, ActiveRecord will manage the `:created_at` and `:updated_at` automatically for you (unless you want to set it manually for some reason off course).